# Trouble saving file uploaded using Python Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, modal-dialog

I am working in Selenium using Python and am working with Chrome.  When I get to a section for a picture upload, I do the following:

```py
    pictureChange = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='custom-file' and @type='file']")
    photoLocation = [I enter the file location on my locally mapped drive]
    pictureChange.send_keys(photoLocation)
```

This seems to work as expected and the picture pops up in an overlay for cropping/zooming before saving the new picture.  The overlay is a div class="modal-box" id="croppicModal."  I am able to interact with the picture to zoom out and whatnot.  But when I click "Save" (either manually or using my program), the new picture does not save.  The overlay just goes away and the old picture is still showing.  If I manually choose the file to upload and then click "Save," it works fine.  It's just when I use the send_keys command to upload the photo that I then can't actually save it.  Any ideas why? Here is the Save button:

```html
    <div class="action-btns"><span class="save-btn rounded-btn">Save</span><span class="croppic-cancel white-btn cancel-btn">Cancel</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try using `WebDriverWait`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
picture_change = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='custom-file' and @type='file']")))
photo_location = "Path/to/the/file"
picture_change.click()
picture_change.send_keys(photo_location)

save_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Save']")))
save_button.click()
```

FYI: the python convention is to use lowercase for variables

Comment: I made these changes but am getting an error:

    picture_change = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='custom-file' and @type='file']")))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: @eec The error can happen from lots of different reasons... 
You'll have to share more of the HTML (around the input of the file) or the WebSite for use to help you more...

Comment: I figured it out!  When I went to grab the HTML around the input of the file for you, I realized there are two lines that match my XPATH search...apparently both appear to work but only one actually does.  I changed my search to do an XPATH lookup using the id, and the upload and save now work.  Thanks!

Comment: @eec I'm glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

If the file is still uploading through your `send_keys` strategy, I think the issue is not with the upload but with the method used to save the file. I'm not sure what clicking strategy you are using, but you could try changing that up with some Javascript.

```
# locate save button
save_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Save']")

# click save button with JS
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", save_button)
```

If this does not work, we may be able to change the way you are uploading the file and see if that helps. But I am not convinced that the actual upload is the issue here.

Comment: I tried a number of methods for clicking the save button (including Javascript like you show).  But I ultimately came to realize that even if I let my program run and then just manually clicked the "Save" button myself, it was not saving.  That's what made me think the initial upload might be the issue.
I just ran a test: I had my program run up until the photo upload part and then had it sleep for 6 seconds while I manually did the upload step.  Then my program successfully clicked the "Save" button on its own, and the picture saved.  So it definitely seems like an issue with the upload.

Comment: It sounds like some Javascript event that ultimately completes the file upload is not running in an automated scenario vs. manual scenario. This seems like a website-specific issue -- perhaps the other user's answer may work for you.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to click on a div element which is not a button. you need to find element with "button" tag that corresponds to a button you are trying to click

Comment: As long as the div has an `onClick()` method one can click it! OP is asking about A. an `<input>` B. a `<span>` using the method of `EC.element_to_be_clickable()` with the `WebDriverWait.until()` should do the trick!